# Is this proof correct about the sum of even numbers $(n+1)n$?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, natural-numbers

I'm very new to proper mathematical proofs and excited about learning them. Yesterday I solved my first proof and wanted to verify it here.

This beginner task comes from the book of a famous Hungarian mathematician Gyula J. Obádovics.

**Prove that the sum of even numbers is $(n+1)n$**

$$2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 2n = (n+1)n$$

**Proof by induction**

For $n = 1$
$$2 = (1+1)1$$
$$2 = 2$$

For $n = k$, assume it is true

$$2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 2k = (k+1)k$$

For $n = k + 1$

$$(2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 2k) + 2(k+1) = ((k+1)+1)(k+1)$$

For the left side, substitute the sum from $n = k$

$$[(k+1)k] + 2(k+1) = ((k+1)+1)(k+1)$$

Which is

$$(k+1)k + 2(k+1) = (k+2)(k+1)$$

Transform the left side to

$$(k+2)(k+1) = (k+2)(k+1)$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: The method is correct, just a technical note: for $n=k+1$ you can't immediately write $2+4+...+2(k+1)=((k+1)+1)(k+1)$, because this is what you want to prove and you still don't know if it is correct or not. What you need is to only write the left hand side and use the induction hypothesis, which will bring you to the right hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In logic sense, it seems correct. The solution just needs some formality.

You have the base case and the assumption for $n = k$ you made is called the *induction hypothesis*. Then, for $n = k+1$, the equality
$$(2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 2k) + 2(k+1) = ((k+1)+1)(k+1)$$
is **what you need to show**. You probably write this not as an equality but a test like "we are checking whether they are equal or not" but as an equality, we don't know whether they are equal or not, yet. Therefore, we start from LHS,
$$(2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 2k) + 2(k+1) = k(k+1)+2(k+1)$$
and above equality comes from the induction hypothesis that we assumed after verifying the base case. Then, you can manipulate RHS a little to have
$$(2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 2k) + 2(k+1) = k(k+1)+2(k+1) = (k+1)(k+2)$$
which holds when $n = k+1$. Therefore, we conclude that argument holds for all $n$ by induction.

Answer (score 3):

After you've been answered, I propose you the following method without (almost) induction. Let $\;S\;$ be the sum of the first $\;n\;$ even numbers, so shall write that sum twice in opposite order:

$$\begin{cases}I&\;S=2+4+6+\ldots+(2n-2)+2n\\{}\\
II&S=2n+(2n-2)+\ldots+6+4+2\end{cases}$$

And now sum up the above two equalities **columnwise**, meaning: sum the elements of the first column $\;2+2n=2n+2\;$ , then the ones in the second column, $\;4+(2n-2)=2n+2\;$ . etc. We get:

$$I+II:\;\;\color{red}{2S}=\overbrace{(2n+2)+(2n+2)+\ldots(2n+2)+(2n+2)}^{n\;\text{times}}=\color{red}{n(2n+2)}=$$

$$=\color{red}{2n(n+1)}\implies\color{red} S=\color{red}{n(n+1)}$$

Comment: Nice trick :) ${}$

Comment: @Botond Note this trick is the standard method I've seen to prove the sum of general arithmetic sequences, such as shown at [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), is $S_n = \frac{n}{2}(a_1 + a_n)$, so you get here that $S = \frac{n}{2}(2 + 2n) = n(n+1)$.